# Bash, execute command but continue with interactive session

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, kerberos

I want to create an alias for `pagsh` that will immediately get me the admin kerberos ticket.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify a command for the `bash` to run, but still continue with the interactive session after the command is done.

My current shot is:

```
alias admin=pagsh -c "bash -c \"kinit xtoth1@ADMIN.META\""
```

but `bash` logically ends right after `kinit` is done. How can I push a custom command into a begging of an interactive session of bash? I still need to run .bashrc normally, therefore I can't use `--rcfile`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My advice would be using a custom bashrc file with `--rcfile` that sources your .bashrc, ex :

`alias admin=pagsh -c "bash --rcfile myrc"`

**myrc** :

```
source ~/.bashrc
kinit xtoth1@ADMIN.META
```

Comment: I presume it should read

`alias admin=pagsh -c "bash --rcfile myrc"`

ie. bash instead of bashrc

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is only a line or two, you can use the cool bash feature of "Process Substitution"[1] to provide it right on the invocation line. e.g. (to run a bash in a specific python virtualenv):

```
bash --rcfile <(echo '. ./pyvenv/bin/activate')
```

multiple lines are not a problem, nor is using vars or helpers:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo echo "Starting at `date`"; echo cd $HOME)
```

[1] `man bash` and look for "Process Substitution". Note that this is not supported on all systems, but it should work on all Linux.

Answer (score 1):

What about following?

```
alias admin='pagsh -c "bash -c \"kinit xtoth1@ADMIN.META; exec bash\""'
```

or even

```
alias admin='pagsh -c "kinit xtoth1@ADMIN.META; exec bash"'
```

might work. (I do not have working openafs environment around to test it properly.)