# Create MakeFile that Runs Docker Image and Changes Directory?

Tags: docker, makefile, mount, cd

I would like to create a makefile that runs a docker container, automatically mount the current folder and within the container CD to the shared directory.

I currently have the following which runs the docker image and mounts the directory with no issue. But I am unsure how to get it to change directory.

```
run:
    docker run --rm -it -v $(PWD):/projects dockerImage bash
```

I've seen some examples where you can append `-c "cd /projects"` at the end so that it is:

`docker run --rm -it -v $(PWD):/projects dockerImage bash -c "cd /projects"`

however it will immediately exit the bash command afterwards. Ive also seen an example where you can append && at the end so that it is the following:

`docker run --rm -it -v $(PWD):/projects dockerImage bash -c "cd /projects &&"`.

Unfortunately the console will just hang.

Comment: `docker run --rm -dit -v $(PWD):/projects dockerImage bash -c "cd /projects &&"` , add the d ?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to set `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile`? Do you mean you want to have an interactive shell which should switch to a specific directory? I suppose you could do `bash -c "cd there && exec bash -i"`

Comment: @tripleee thank you that worked. WORKDIR would be an okay solution but my projects share the same container. I have different projects and on startup I want it to CD to the project location for each unique makefile command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash, execute command but continue with interactive session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584736/bash-execute-command-but-continue-with-interactive-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the working directory in your `docker run` command with the `-w` option. So you can do something like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(PWD):/projects -w /projects dockerImage bash
```

You can find this option in the official docs here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/.